# reading a text file line by line using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am trying to read in lines from a text file that are in this form;
34.925,150.977
35.012,151.034
34.887,150.905

I am currently trying to use this methodology, which obviously isn't working. Any help would be appreciated.

```
var ltlng = [];
var txtFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    txtFile.open("GET", "C:\Gmap\LatLong\Coordinates.txt", true);
    txtFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (txtFile.readyState === 4) {  
        if (txtFile.status === 200) {  // Makes sure it's found the file.
           lines = txtFile.responseText.split("\n"); // separate each line into an array
             ltlng.push(new google.maps.LatLng(lines.split(",")[0],lines.split(",")[1]); //create the marker icons latlong array
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This may cause because same origin policy http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy . You need to do your ajax calls from same domain instead of local file

Comment: try `file:///C:/Gmap/LatLong/Coordinates.txt` instead of `C:\Gmap\LatLong\Coordinates.txt`

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work for me. Im going to try using jquery as its a little more textfile reading friendly

Answer (score 0):

`XMLHttpRequest` works when resources are called by `HTTP/S` protocol (and not `file` protocol, as in your example)

So to make your code work, you should try this code along with a web server